# MS Access Union, Order By mess up my query order

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, ms-access-2007, union

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumDollarsSold,  
    "PHOA" As CustomerNo
FROM  
    dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE 
    ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.[CustomerNo]) IN ("PHOM","PHOB", "PHOA", "HOMP")) 
    AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN [BeginDate] AND [EndDate])

UNION

SELECT TOP 9 
    SUM(DollarsSold), CustomerNo 
FROM 
    dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE 
    ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo) NOT IN ("PHOM","PHOB", "PHOA", "HOMP")) 
    AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN [BeginDate] AND [EndDate])
GROUP BY 
    dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo 
ORDER BY 
    1 DESC;
```

When I run two queries separately, the 2nd part of query is returning the output I expect:

[image: Correct]

but when I run it together with `UNION`, then the order is somehow mixed up:

[image: WRONG].

In the code `ORDER BY 1 DESC`, `1` refers to the first column which is the sum.

I have tried

```
ORDER BY SUM(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) DESC;
```

instead but it returns an error:

[Err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBmOF.jpg)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBmOF.jpg)

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

**Update**: this is the current query output:

[[image]]

Desired output would look like:

[image]

(I cut and pasted the row 2~10 from the picture 1). I hope this would help with your understanding!

My current query:

```
Sum of Dollar | Customer
--------------+----------
     10       |    A   
      8       |    B
      1       |    Q
```

Desired query output

```
14 | B_Total
10 | A
 5 | C
```

B_Total (14) is the sum of X (4), Y (3), Z (2) AND B (5)

**Update:** current query

```
SELECT 
    SumDollarsSold, CustomerNo, MyOrder 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumDollarsSold, 
         "PHOALLE" AS CustomerNo, 1 AS MyOrder
     FROM 
         dbo_SO_SalesHistory
     WHERE 
         ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.[CustomerNo]) IN ("PHOMIN","PHOALLE","PHOBROO","PHOMP"))  
         AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate])
     UNION
     SELECT TOP 9 
         SUM(DollarsSold), CustomerNo, 2 as MyOrder 
     FROM 
         dbo_SO_SalesHistory
     WHERE 
         ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo) NOT IN ("PHOM","PHOA","PHOB","PHOM")) 
         AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate])
     GROUP BY 
         dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo
     ORDER BY 
         1 DESC
) a 
ORDER BY 
    MyOrder, SumDollarsSold DESC;
```

Comment: The ordering looks correct to me -- by the first column in descending numeric order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the reply. My desired query output will be like Customer, PHOA -> WE -> CA -> INT -> TO -> FIS like the first picture. The 2nd picture is correct in terms of the descending numeric order. Yet, I want the 2nd highest dollar sold customer listed in the 2nd row, 3rd in 3rd row etc..

Comment: You need to treat the result of the UNION as a sub-query, then write a SELECT statement based on that with an ORDER BY that will apply to the entire result set. As you've written it here, the ORDER BY will only apply to the second query in the UNION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you UNION no order is guaranteed, so you are losing the ORDER BY that you've already done on the second query. You can add another field to make sure that the first record is always on top, but then you do need to include that in your selected fields. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SumDollarsSold, CustomerNo, MyOrder 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumDollarsSold, 
         "PHOA" AS CustomerNo, 1 AS MyOrder
     FROM 
         dbo_SO_SalesHistory
     WHERE 
         ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.[CustomerNo]) IN ("PHOM","PHOB", "PHOA", "PHOM"))  
         AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate])
     UNION
     (SELECT TOP 9 
         SUM(DollarsSold), CustomerNo, 2 as MyOrder 
     FROM 
         dbo_SO_SalesHistory
     WHERE 
         ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo) NOT IN ("PHOM","PHOB", "PHOA", "PHOM")) 
         AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate])
     GROUP BY 
         dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo
     ORDER BY 
         SUM(DollarsSold) DESC)
) a 
ORDER BY 
    MyOrder, SumDollarsSold DESC;
```

Comment: sorry I have mentioned that I want PHOA (the first query) to be the top result on the first row. And PHOA is sum of "PHOM","PHOB", "PHOA", "HOMP"

Comment: @JBowman Oh, I see what you are saying. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! If there is anything that I can clarify, please don't hesitate to ask me any.

Comment: Thank you so much again, just a quick question: I get the The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input able or query '2'. Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed a typo in my answer (thanks to reformatting by @marc_s) that I've now fixed. The "2 as MyOrder" was on the wrong line. Take another look now.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time. Would you please take a look at the edit for a better understanding of my question? I'm terribly sorry that I have misguided you at the first place..

Comment: Ah, I missed the "TOP 9" part of the second query. So you'll just want to add the ORDER BY back to the second query in addition to the ORDER BY on the overall query.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for bothering you again. I'm so sorry. But I'm getting 'The ORDER BY expression (SUM(DollarsSold)) includes fields that are not selected by the query. Only those fields requested in the first query can be included in an ORDER BY expression. 
Again, I'm so sorry again for keep asking..

Comment: You can try  using `1` for the ORDER BY like you had in your initial query.

Comment: and I'm back to square 1.. which means the same result as above. I'm so sorry for have kept bugging you.

Comment: Can you paste the current query here?

Comment: I just did! Please check the update. and please let me know if you have any other concern or question. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more small thing - the second query needs parens around it I guess. Updating the answer. Hopefully this one does it!

Comment: YESS! WOW! Thank you so so much! You are awesome! Thank you so much for your kindness. I really appreciate that you didn't give up on me, unlike everyone else. I hope you have a great day! You truly deserve it!

Comment: Great! Sorry it took longer than it should have since I made a few typos, but I'm glad we got there.